# How to retrieve json data from other site(s) and decoding it using cURL?

Tags: php, json, curl, laravel, laravel-4

### Situation

I got stuck while trying to use cURL to retrieve data from my other site

When I go to `http://localhost/api/distributors`

- I can see all the json. :)

BUT When I use the CLI and run this command `curl -i --user test:1234 http://localhost/api/distributors`

I couldn't connect to it, or see any json at all.

I am not sure what went wrong.
I am positive that I type the right username and password.

### Details

Here is my route.

`Route::get('/api/distributors', array('before' => 'auth.basic', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@api_index'));`

It called `DistributorController` > `api_index`

and here is my `api_index` function

```
public function api_index()
{
$distributors = [];

foreach(Distributor::all() as $distributor)
{
    $user = $distributor->user()->first();

    $distributors[$distributor->id] = [

    'user' => $user->toArray(),
    'distributor' => $distributor->toArray(),
    'contacts' => $distributor->contacts()->get()->toArray(),
    'addresses' => $distributor->addresses()->get()->toArray()
    ];
}

$json_string = json_encode($distributors, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

return $json_string;
}
```

### Questions

- I am not sure where should I stick the decode section of my code.
  Should it go into the same function of of `encoding` ?

It look like this :

```
<h1>Decode</h1>

<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://localhost/api/distributors");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "test:1234");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>


<?php $distributor = json_decode($body, TRUE); ?>

<!-- Test -->
<li><?php echo $distributor['distributor']['company_name']; ?></li>
```

### Note

I only have a problem when trying to connect using cURL.

Comment: Put debug echo with __LINE__ __FILE__ and see , add laravel tag

Comment: Route::get ? curl is not post ? Try Route::any

Comment: ok. I will try that now.

Comment: `debug echo with LINE FILE`, what do you mean by that ? Also `Route::any` doesn't work either, when I run this `curl -i --user test:1234 http://localhost/api/distributors`

Comment: Does `echo curl_error($ch)` say something?

Comment: @lukasgeiter : Where exactly should I do that ? Keep in mind that my decoding part never get execute because I don't know where to stick it.

Comment: It load fine after I did that.

Comment: With loaded fine you mean you got the json??

Comment: Yes. I got the json to load. see [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/Capture.JPG)

Comment: And if you remove `echo curl_error($ch)` it's broken again?`

Comment: No, it still working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67550/discussion-between-iggy-and-lukasgeiter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 3 Main Things to fix :

### - add this to your `routes.php`

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api', 'before' => 'auth.basic|api'), function(){
    Route::resource('url', 'UrlController');
});
```

### - add 2 things in `filters.php`

1. Add `auth.basic`

   // Auth Basic

   ```
   Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
   {
       return Auth::basic("username");
   });
   ```
2. Add `api` Filter

   // API
   Route::filter('api', function() {

   ```
   $user = Auth::user();

   if ($user){
       // Let them in
   } 
   else{
       return Response::view('errors.404', array(), 404);
   }
   ```

   });

### - Create NEW `controller` function and throw this in there ..

```
<?php

class UrlController extends \BaseController {

    // public function index(){
    //  return Response::json(User::all());
    // }

    public function index()
    {
        $distributors = [];

        foreach(Distributor::all() as $distributor)
        {
            $user = $distributor->user()->first();

            $distributors[$distributor->id] = [

            'user' => $user->toArray(),
            'distributor' => $distributor->toArray(),
            'contacts' => $distributor->contacts()->get()->toArray(),
            'addresses' => $distributor->addresses()->get()->toArray()
            ];
        }

        return Response::json($distributors);
    }
}
```